# Drawing works fine with glDrawArrays, but is failing using glDrawElements

Tags: java, scala, opengl

My shader works fine, and I can draw with glDrawArrays, but am having a hard time getting glDrawElements to work. I've added comments to where lwjgl function calls are different than standard openGL. Code:

```
import org.lwjgl.Sys
import org.lwjgl.glfw._
import org.lwjgl.opengl._
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.FloatBuffer
import  org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks._
import  org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW._
import  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11._
import  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15._
import  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20._
import  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30._
import  org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil._
import  org.lwjgl.BufferUtils._
import hands._
import javafx.scene.shape.CullFace


class Test {

    val vertex_positions:  Array[Float] = Array(
     -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    )

    val vertex_indices: Array[Int] = Array(
      0, 1, 2    
    )

    // We need to strongly reference callback instances.
    val errorCallback: GLFWErrorCallback = Callbacks.errorCallbackPrint();
    val keyCallback: GLFWKeyCallback = new GLFWKeyCallback() {
      @Override
      def invoke(window: Long , key: Int, scancode: Int , action: Int , mods: Int) {
        if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
          glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE) // We will detect this in our rendering loop
      }
    }

    val WIDTH = 800
    val HEIGHT = 600 

    def run(): Unit = {
            System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Sys.getVersion() + "!")  

            try {

                val vertBuffer = hands.createFlippedBuffer(vertex_positions)
                val indexBuffer = hands.createFlippedBuffer(vertex_indices)

                // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
                // will print the error message in System.err.
                glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback)

                // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
                if ( glfwInit() != GL_TRUE )
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW")

                // Configure our window
                glfwDefaultWindowHints() // optional, the current window hints are already the default
                glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE) // the window will stay hidden after creation
                glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE) // the window will be resizable
                glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
                glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
                glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

                // Create the window
                val window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL)
                if ( window == NULL )
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window")

                // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.        
                glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback)

                // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
                val vidmode: ByteBuffer = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor())
                // Center our window
                glfwSetWindowPos(
                        window,
                        (GLFWvidmode.width(vidmode) - WIDTH) / 2,
                        (GLFWvidmode.height(vidmode) - HEIGHT) / 2)

                // Make the OpenGL context current
                glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)
                // Enable v-sync
                glfwSwapInterval(1)

                // Make the window visible
                glfwShowWindow(window)

                // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
                // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
                // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
                // creates the ContextCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
                // bindings available for use.
                GLContext.createFromCurrent()

                //create shader, and use it as program
                val shader = new Shader()
                glUseProgram(shader.program)

                val vao = glGenVertexArrays()
                glBindVertexArray(vao)

                val vbo = glGenBuffers()
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
                //http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL15.html#glBufferData%28int,%20java.nio.FloatBuffer,%20int%29
                glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  vertBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

                //this function accepts false instead of GL_FALSE
                glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false , 0, 0)
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

                val ebo = glGenBuffers()
                glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo)
                //http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL15.html#glBufferData%28int,%20java.nio.ShortBuffer,%20int%29
                glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW)


                // Set the clear color
                glClearColor(0, 0, 0.4f, 1)
                // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
                // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
                //glfwWindowShouldClose produces a GL_FALSE, instead of a boolean value
                while ( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_FALSE ) {

                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) // clear the framebuffer

                glBindVertexArray(vao)
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

                glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo)

                //http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html#glDrawElements%28int,%20java.nio.ShortBuffer%29
                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexBuffer)
                //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 9)

                glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

                // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
                // invoked during this call.
                glfwPollEvents();
            }

            // Release window and window callbacks            
            glfwDestroyWindow(window)
            keyCallback.release()
        } finally {
            // Terminate GLFW and release the GLFWerrorfun
            glfwTerminate()
            errorCallback.release()
        }
    }

}

object main{

      def main( args: Array[String] ) = {
          new Test().run();
      }
    }
```

Comment: What happens? Segfault? Black screen? Solid black shapes? Are there any OpenGL errors?

Comment: There appear to be no openGL errors. A screen the color of the clear color appears, but not the triangle I am trying to draw.

Answer (score 1):

There are two variations of `glDrawElements()` that are quite different in how the last argument is defined and used:

1. One takes "data" as argument. The exact type of the argument depends on the language bindings, but it's typically something like a pointer in C/C++, a buffer in Java, etc.
2. One takes an integer offset as argument.

Option 2 is used if a buffer is currently bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. The integer given as the last argument is an offset (in bytes) relative to the start of the bound buffer.

Option 1 is used if **no** buffer is bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. In this case, the last argument directly specifies the index data.

The problem in your code is that you're mixing the two. You have a buffer bound, so you need to use option 2. But you're using option 1. The correct call in your case would be:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
```

Note that the *count* (second argument) is given in units of vertices, while the *offset* (last argument) is given in units of bytes. Since you're using the entire buffer, and the offset is 0, it does not make a difference here. But it's a frequent source of errors.

In weakly typed languages like C/C++, there's actually only one `glDrawElements()` call, and the offset for option 2 is cast to a pointer. This is also the reason why you get a crash if you use the call from option 1 by mistake, instead of an OpenGL error. Based on the spec, which documents the C/C++ bindings, there is only a single call, so there's no such thing as calling the "wrong" entry point in this case. They are only different entry points in more strongly typed languages.

Comment: Thank you for the description! Unfortunately, I'm still getting what appears to be the same error, with nothing showing up. This appears to happen even if I do not bind anything to the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY name and use option 1 in this case.

Comment: This solved my problem in python using PyOpenGL. Instead of glDrawElements(..., 0), I had to use glDrawElements(..., None).